# Animation error after upgrade from Angular 13 to 14

Tags: angular, animation

I have come up with not so complicated animation that runs in one way on `:enter` and in reverse on `:leave`. It worked just fine. But after upgrading to Angular 14 it broke.

```
import { 
animate, style, transition, keyframes, trigger, AnimationStyleMetadata 
} from '@angular/animations';

const inOutKeyframes: readonly AnimationStyleMetadata[] = [
    style({
        offset: 0,
        opacity: 0,
        transform: 'scale(.8)',
        /** Height - (padding * 2 (top + bottom)) + (margin-bottom * 2?) */
        marginTop: 'calc(-100% + (16px * 2 + 24px))',
        zIndex: -1,
    }),
    style({
        offset: .5,
        opacity: .7,
        transform: 'scale(.8)',
        marginTop: '-30%',
        zIndex: -1,
    }),
    style({
        offset: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        transform: '',
        marginTop: '',
        zIndex: -1,
    }),
];

export const cardAnimations = [
    trigger('card', [
        transition(':enter', [
            animate('300ms ease-out', keyframes([...inOutKeyframes])),
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
            animate('300ms ease-out', keyframes([...inOutKeyframes].reverse())),
        ]),
    ]),
];
```

The animation is only used in one component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'rita-create-areas',
    templateUrl: './create-areas.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create-areas.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    animations: cardAnimations,
})
export class CreateAreasComponent { ... }
```

```
Error: NG03404: The animation trigger "card" has failed to build due to the following errors:
 - NG03200: Please ensure that all keyframe offsets are in order
 - NG03010: The CSS property "opacity" that exists between the times of "0ms" and "300ms" is also being animated in a parallel animation between the times of "0ms" and "150ms"
 - NG03010: The CSS property "transform" that exists between the times of "0ms" and "300ms" is also being animated in a parallel animation between the times of "0ms" and "150ms"
 - NG03010: The CSS property "marginTop" that exists between the times of "0ms" and "300ms" is also being animated in a parallel animation between the times of "0ms" and "150ms"
 - NG03010: The CSS property "zIndex" that exists between the times of "0ms" and "300ms" is also being animated in a parallel animation between the times of "0ms" and "150ms"
```

The error disappears if I comment out `:enter`, or `:leave`. I am not sure why, but I cannot have both, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular 14, it will complain if the offsets do not correspond. The problem was with the reverse animation since the animation offsets went in order `0, .5, 1`. Removing offset will work since the default behaviour is to calculate offsets on its own.